# Split number in random parts

Tags: algorithm, random

This is just a problem I thought of while I was in bed last night :) .

How do you split a number, let's call it N, in M random parts, so that each part has the same probability to be a number from 0 to N.

Eg: N= 5, M=3

The algorithm should return an array like one of these:

```
[0,2,3]   //0 + 2 +3 =5
[1,1,3]  
[0,0,5]  
[3,2,0]  
[2,2,1]  
...etc
```

The programming languange doesn't really matter.

Comment: Do you need to have all the numbers have an equal probability if you choose one from the matrix? i.e. if N=5  then matrix[x][y] has a 1/6 chance of returning a 1?

Comment: Yes. So let's say we run the algorithm 1M times. After all this runs we count how many times each number appears on each position in the array. The numbers should be ~equal for all numbers and all positions (0 appears 100 times on the first position, 1 appears 100 times on the second position, 4 appears 100 times on the first position, etc...)

Comment: Complexity of algo is important for you?

Comment: No... It's not homework or anything else, I just thought of this and I want to know a possible solution. Of course, optimal solutions are the best :)

Comment: I suspect that this isn't possible.  With your `N=5; M=3` example, consider that the only way that 5 can appear is in some rearrangement of [0, 0, 5].  So right there, you've got 0 appearing at least twice as many times as 5.

Comment: Actually in that case 0 appears once on the first position and once on the second position and 5 appears once in the third position. (it doesn't count as '0 appears twice' )

Comment: Sure, but now add up across the positions.  You want number of 0s in position 1 ~= number of 0s in position 2 ~= number of 0s in position 3 ~= number of 5s in position 1 ~= number of 5s in position 2 ~= number of 5s in position 3, right?  So adding across the positions, you get total number of 5s ~= total number of 0s.  And that's not going to happen.

Answer (score 2):

I just subscribed to share my results about this particular problem. I've come to a solution that pleases me, even if, obviously, it's not a 100% random number split. But it fits my needs, and it is very light on resources.

I give you the code for the method (it's a recursive method) with comments on specific parts (others are pretty straight-forward I think). The code has been made in AS3, but the language is easy to read :

```
/**
 * This function splits a unique number into many numbers whose total equals to the one given as a parameter.
 * The function only works for size equals to a power of 2, but I think it can be easily done for any size,
 * by making as many "power of 2" calls as necessary to get a good final result.
 * @param   total The expected value of the sum of the resulting numbers
 * @param   minValue The minimum value each number can take
 * @param   maxValue The maximum value each number can take
 * @param   size The number of numbers we want to split the total into
 * @param   stepNum The step number of the recursive calls. Used to enhance the results of the algorithm.
 * @return
 */
    private function splitTotalInTwo(total:int, minValue:int, maxValue:int, size:int, stepNum:int):Vector.<int>
    {
        var result:Vector.<int> = new Vector.<int>();

        // we determine the min and max values allowed for the random generated number so that it doesn't 
        // make the second group impossible to process with success
        var minRand:int = Math.max(size * minValue, total - (size * maxValue));
        var maxRand:int = Math.min(size * maxValue, total - (size * minValue));

        // the balanceFactor is used to make the split tighter in the early stages of the recursive algorithm, 
        // therefore ensuring a best number distribution in the end. 
        // You can comment the next three lines to see the number distribution of th inital algorithm.
        // You can alsocchange the balancefactor to get which results you like most. 
        // This var good also be passed as parameter to fine tune the algorithm a little bit more.
        var balanceFactor:Number = 0.4;
        var delta:int = Math.floor((maxRand - minRand) * (0.4 / stepNum));
        minRand += delta;
        maxRand -= delta;

        var random:int = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxRand - minRand)) + minRand;
        if (size > 1)
        {
            result = result.concat(splitTotalInTwo(random, minValue, maxValue, size / 2, stepNum+1), splitTotalInTwo(total - random, minValue, maxValue, size / 2, stepNum+1));
        }
        else 
        {
            result.push(random);
            result.push(total - random);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 1):

Lets assume we have a method that generates a uniformly random distribution of numbers between `[0,N]`. An obvious way is to successively generate `M` random numbers in the range from `[0,N]` where we update N after each generation, since the sum of all generated numbers has to equal `N`. You would have to mathematically prove that this will result in a uniformly randomly distributed collection of pairs `[x1,x2,....,xM]`. I would say that this is **not trivial**. (For instance your example where the first number is randomly chosen to be 5, the following two numbers **have** to be zero as the sum can not exceed `N=5` and therefore the randomnness is biased)

Another '*brute force*' method that you might consider is generating a collection of all possible permutations `[x1,x2,....,xM]` where the sum `x1+x2+...+xM = N`. If the collection contains `Y` possible permutations you can then use our previously defined random generator to get a random number in the range `[1,Y]` and select that element from your collection

Note that this is just of the top of my head and if you want to ensure truely random uniform distributions you have to check these proposals mathematically.

Edit: I also just realized that probably, they way you described the problem, the order in which the number is split is irrelevant (i.e. `[0,2,3]` is the same as `[2,3,0]` is the same as `[0,3,2]`). This reduces the number of total unique permutation in the ensemble of `Y` groupings

Comment: Actually, couldn't you just make an array with all the unique permutations where x1+x2+...+xM = N and then randomize the rows in it so the numbers "appear" random?

Comment: You could, but the OP wants to select a single permutation, so if you generate the complete ensemble, you just need to pick one at random and the shuffling seems pointless to me

Comment: Hmm... But we should select SOME of the permutations from the total of Y so that each number appears on each position the same number of times, and then choose a random one from these.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but I had this exact same question, and sorely needed a definite answer for a project I'm developing. After several days of studying probability, distribution functions, and the like, the answer finally came to me (while in bed last night :)

First, I term this as a bucket distribution since it's equivalent to the following algorithm:

- Take a set of buckets (number of parts) and a set of items (length of range).
- One by one, drop each item into a randomly selected bucket.

(It could even be implemented in code this way, but this would be inefficient for a large number of items.)

There are two variants to the question:

### Variant 1: Fractional

Although the OP implies integer-sized ranges, an alternative is to divide the range into decimal-sized parts.
(e.g., random distribution of water into buckets)

### Variant 2: Integral

Divide an integer-length range into integer-length parts.
(e.g., random distribution of apples into buckets)

---

### Solution to 1: Fractional

To split a range into random fractionally-sized pieces is actually pretty trivial:

1. Generate a set of random numbers on the range (0,1], one for each bucket or piece.
2. Multiply each generated number by the number of items divided by the sum of all the random numbers.

The first step requires a 0-exclusive range to avoid any theoretical chance of division-by-zero, but the 1 in the range could technically be any number.

The second step effectively scales the sum-length of the generated numbers over the range of items. The big-O complexity of this is pretty decent too: O(2n) (where n is buckets or parts)

---

### Solution to 2: Integral

To generate integer ranges seemed tricky at first, but I realized how to do it by continuing the solution to 1:

3. Floor each generated random number after multiplying by 'number of items' / 'sum of random numbers'.
4. Sum the results of these and subtract this sum from the number of items (i.e., get the remaining items).
5. Iterate through this result, and increment a random bucket for each of the remaining items.

By step 5, the remaining items is most likely equal to, but never more than the number of buckets. Thus the complexity of this algorithm is still pretty decent: O(3n)

---

### TL;DR: The Code

In code (I prefer Javascript):

```js
function bucketDistribution(buckets,items,integral=true) {
    // generate 'buckets' list of random numbers over (0,1]
    var list = [],
        sum = 0;

    for(let i=0; i<buckets; i++) {
        let num = 1 - Math.random(); // flip Math.random's [0,1) to (0,1]
        list.push(num);
        sum += num;
    }

    // scale over range 'items'
    var factor = items / sum;
    sum = 0;

    for(let i=0; i<buckets; i++) {
        list[i] *= factor;

        // if using integers, floor and re-sum numbers
        if(integral) {
            list[i] = Math.floor(list[i]);
            sum += list[i];
        }
    }

    // if generating decimal ranges, we're done
    if(!integral) return list;

    // numbers were floored; distribute remainder
    var remaining = items - sum;

    for(let i=0; i<remaining; i++) {
        let bucket = Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length);
        list[bucket]++;
    }

    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try my approach. Initially I calculated amount of posible results and after choose random (implementation on C#):

```
class Program
{
    private static int[,] dp;

    private static void Populate(int m, int n)
    {
        dp[0, 0] = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i <= m; i++)
        {
            dp[i, 0] = 1;
            for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
            {
                dp[i, j] = dp[i - 1, j] + dp[i, j - 1];
            }
        }
    }

    private static int[] GetResultAt(int index, int m, int n)
    {
        int[] result = new int[m];

        while (m > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
            {
                if (index <= dp[m - 1, i] && dp[m - 1, i] > 0)
                {
                    m--;
                    result[m] = n - i;
                    n = i;
                    break;
                }
                index = index - dp[m - 1, i];
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int n = 5;
        int m = 3;
        dp = new int[m + 1, n + 1];
        Populate(m, n);

        int randomPosition = 7;// Random value from 1 and dp[m,n] range.
        int[] result = GetResultAt(randomPosition, m, n);

        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

Define required `m`, `n` and `randomPosition` to get result.
Complexity of this algo is **O(M*N)** for precalc and **O(M+N)** for get a random array.

Comment: Isn't the populate complexity ~O(M*N^2) ?  actually: O(M*N*(N+1)/2) ? Can you explain the algorithm and how does this achieve uniform distribution?

Comment: uniform distribution achieved because used random index or result. Distribution will be same as this number choose distribution, standard random use uniform distribution

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Integer[] sliceUnequally(int value, int numberOfSlices) {
    if (numberOfSlices > value) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                String.format("!!! Cannot carve %d into %d slices", value, numberOfSlices));
    }

    final Integer[] slices = new Integer[numberOfSlices];

    int allocated = numberOfSlices;
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSlices; i++) {
        if (i == (numberOfSlices - 1)) {
            slices[i] = 1 + (value - allocated);
        } else {
            int slice = new Double((value - allocated) * random.nextDouble()).intValue();
            slices[i] = 1 + slice;
            allocated += slice;
        }
    }

    return slices;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain how this works and why is it correct?